# Glassfish Error when deploying working GF 2.1 to Glassfish 3 and switching to maven at the same time - Killing me!

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

Everything builds just fine in Maven and Ant, but will only deploy when building with Ant. It is an EJB jar I am deploying that is @Stateless and has @WebService tags as well

```
[#|2010-06-30T19:23:29.045-0500|SEVERE|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while deploying the app 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=my.package.SalesManagerBean/reportsManager,Local 3.x interface =cmy.package.ReportsManagerLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=null,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:587)
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2411)
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EjbBundleDescriptor.visit(EjbBundleDescriptor.java:726)
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.Application.visit(Application.java:1749)
 at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:190)
 at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:162)
 at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:79)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:615)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:557)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:265)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:186)
 at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:276)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:314)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:329)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:832)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:85)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:891)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:880)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:138)
 at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:350)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:89)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:66)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:186)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
 at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:160)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1518)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:229)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:229)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:239)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:811)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:708)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1017)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:171)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
 at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:526)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:507)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Everything builds just fine in Maven and Ant, but will only deploy when building with Ant.

Then there is a difference somewhere between the EJB-JAR built by Ant and the one built by Maven. But I don't think the stacktrace will help here.

Could you tell us more about the structure of your app? Can you run `jar xvf myejb.jar` on both of your EJB-JARs and post the output? Can you show the structure of your maven project (e.g with `tree myproject`)? Can you show the `pom.xml`?

Also, why did you mention GF 2.1 in the title of the question? Does this have anything to do with the problem? Does the EJB-JAR built by Maven deploy on GF 2.1?